# How to create dynamic forms without reactive forms in angular6?

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have a class object with fields :
Template = {
   id ?: text,
   widgets ?: any[]
}

whenever i click on add button, the input fields refreshes in the html page
TypeScript and HTML :

```js
template : Template= new Template();
ngOnInIt() {
   this.template.widgets = [];
}
addWidget(W_id :String){
    this.template.widgets.push({
      index : null,
      title: null
    });
}
```

```html
  <mat-form-field>
<mat-select id="selectWidget" placeholder="Add Widget"[(value)]="w_id" >
<mat-option value='image'>Image</mat-option>
<mat-option value='title'>Title</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" class="float-right" (click)="addWidget(w_id)"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add</button>
              
<div *ngFor="let widget of template.widgets; let i = index">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width template-style">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Index" [(ngModel)]="widget.index" name="index" >
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Page Title" [(ngModel)]="widget.title" name="title" >  
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using `formArray` in this case?

Comment: In there are more than 5 widgets types, it will be difficult to patch value for each widget with different fields ( in case of edit feature )

Comment: But as per my experience this method would lead to more complex behavior at the end, rest your choice

Comment: is there any method to copy to convert object response from API to formgroups directly ?

Comment: try to use `patchValue` directly over the same object

Comment: that requires each data member to patch its value , the way : 
 this.template.id = this.answer.id;

Comment: No, I don't think so. It will automatically construct the form filled with the data in your object the way we initialize form.

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value#patchvalue Might be usefull to you

Comment: you can use [(ngModel)]="widget[i].title" (note:personally I prefer Reactive Forms)